# ¿Por que no me imprime el resultado de un arreglo?

Tags: c, array

Tengo entendido que hasta cierta parte esta bien mi código pero en cierta parte de la sintaxis no hace bien el trabajo

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

main()
{
int a,b,c;
char nom[3][15],bus;

for(b=0;b<3;b++){
        for(c=0;c<1;c++){
            printf("Ingrese el nombre del alumno: ");
            fflush( stdin );
            scanf("%s",&nom[b][c]);
            printf("Ingrese la calificacion del alumno: ");
            fflush( stdin );
            scanf("%d",&a);
        }
}

printf("¿cual alumno deseea buscar? ");
fflush( stdin );
scanf(" %s", &bus);

if(nom[b]=="bus"){
    printf("Nomre: %s Calificacion: %d", nom[b][c], a);
}

getch();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Errores y cosas a mejorar en tu código:

**uso de fflush**

```
fflush( stdin );
```

Esta función solo debe utilizarse con dispositivos de salida. Lo dice muy clarito en la [documentación](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fflush/):

> In all other cases, the behavior depends on the specific library implementation. In some implementations, **flushing a stream open for reading** causes its input buffer to be cleared (**but this is not portable expected behavior**).

**cuidado al leer cadenas**

```
scanf("%s",&nom[b][c]);
```

Hay formas mucho más limpias de pasar el puntero al inicio de la cadena de caracteres:

- `nom` es un puntero doble `char**`
- `nom[b]` es un puntero simple `char*`
- `nom[b][c]` es un caracter `char`

Dado que la función te está pidiendo un `char*`, lo que te interesaría poner (por claridad) en este punto es:

```
scanf("%s",nom[b]);
```

**tabula el código**

El código bien tabulado es facil de seguir y de entender, mientras que el que está mal tabulado (o no está tabulado) es otro cantar.

**cuidado al comparar cadenas**

```
if(nom[b]=="bus")
```

Seguro que has pensado que esta instrucción va a coger las dos cadenas y a compararlas entre sí para saber si son iguales... no hace exactamente eso.

Estamos en C, que es casi lo más simplón justo por detrás de ensamblador... y aquí el código hace literalmente lo que le pides... pero literalmente no me refiero a que haga lo que tú estás pensando que va a hacer:

`nom[b]` es un puntero a `char`, y `"bus"` es un puntero a `const char`... así que el operador de comparación se limita a comparar dichos punteros, es decir, compara **sus direcciones de memoria**. Si ambos punteros apuntan a la misma dirección el resultado será `true`... no es lo que esperabas.

Para comparar cadenas de caracteres tienes que usar una función o un algoritmo que te quieras currar... para empezar puedes utilizar `strcmp`:

```
if( strcmp(nom[b],"bus") == 0 )
```

¿Cómo funciona `strcmp`? Coge los dos punteros y va comparándolos caracter a caracter hasta que encuentra una diferencia o llega al final de la cadena. La comparación la hace restando los dos caracteres en cuestión... si el resultado es distinto de cero es que son diferentes. Así, si el valor retornado es cero entonces `nom[b]=="bus"`.